# Microsoft hotfix install over network fails 0x80070003

Tags: windows-7

I have been been trying to figure this out for a long time now and have made no progress so I'm hoping someone can help.

I have an installer script to install a predefined set of Microsoft hotfixes on a new Windows 7 boxes.  When installing from a network mapped drive with"

"C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "Z:\Documents\OS_Hotfixes\Win7-2008\32bit\Windows7SP1\Windows6.1-KB2559049-x86.msu"

I get an error: Installer encountered an error: 0x80070003 The system cannot find the path specified.

If I run the same hotfix from the local machine:

"C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\Share\HostDocuments\OS_Hotfixes\Win7-2008\32bit\Windows7SP1\Windows6.1-KB2559049-x86.msu"

The hotfix installs just fine with no unexpected errors.

All hotfixes act the same way so it's not this specific one.  I have also run sfc /scannow on the box with no success.

This is a Windows 7 SP1 32 bit host.

Comment: Most probably problem is in file path and in `wusa.exe`. Probably `wusa.exe` doesn't understand network addreses (and mapped drives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I know what's the installer's problem, but you can circumvent it if you just put it all in a script - copy the hotfix, run it, and delete the hotfix installation file.

Also, you should try putting the script, the wusa.exe and the update files in the same network folder.

Comment: That's a possibility, would be slower than running the msu files directly from the network, but quicker than waiting to pull the full package off the server then do the install.  Tomorrow I'm going to look into symlinks and see if it could help.

Comment: Have you tried the second option? putting all files (along with wusa.exe) in the network share? this way you won't need to copy the files.

Comment: I ended up using Eliad's method.  I copy the msu file from the server to the target machine and run it locally.  Works well and very little delay.